# Using a while loop how would you print out the average of the stored strings in the while loop?

Tags: python

So I have written up parts of a program that says I can take in any number of positive numbers and zero, and to exit the program I can write a negative number. I now want to print out the average of this. How would I print out the average?

The bits so far.

```
i = int(eval(input('Enter a number positive number. Enter a negative number to exit: ')))
while i >= 0:
    i = int(eval(input('Enter a number positive number. Enter a negative number to exit: ')))
```

Comment: instead of `i=` try `i+=` inside the loop. also add a `j` counter that increments every time a non negative number is added. at the end print i/j (which is the average)

Comment: Please, for the love of god and everything that is holy, [remove the `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice).

Comment: Why are you using both `eval()` *and* `int()`? Use one or the other, as long as it is not `eval()`.

Comment: When solving a problem like this, the first step is to turn off your computer. Then get a piece of paper and pencil and describe **in words** the steps needed to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

how about something like this?

```
j = 0
total = 0
while True: #"infinite" loop
    i = int(input('Enter a number positive number. Enter a negative number to exit:'))
    if i < 0: #loop escape clause
        break
    total += i
    j+=1
if j > 0: #avoid division by zero
    average = total/j #rounded average
else:
    average = 0
```

Comment: Upon testing the code, I don't see the average when I hit a negative number. When I enter a negative number, I want to be able to see the average.

Comment: @PM2Ring you are correct, i forgot sum is a builtin. i edited my answer